# Matplotlib animation: first frame remains in canvas when using blit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two rotating ellipses using the Matplotlib animation library, and I managed to get it working (more or less). The problem is that the first frame that is being rendered does not update, so while I got two rotating ellipses in my canvas, I also have the ellipses in their original position/orientation. Check out my simple piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
e1 = Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=60)
e2 = Ellipse(xy=(0.8, 0.8), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=100)

def init():
    ax.add_patch(e1)
    ax.add_patch(e2)
    return [e1,e2]

def animate(i):
    e1.angle = e1.angle + 0.5
    e2.angle = e2.angle + 0.5
    return [e1,e2]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Any idea how to fix this? I could of course turn off blit, but that makes it horribly slow, so that's not really an option.

**EDIT: Final (working) Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
e1 = Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=60)
e2 = Ellipse(xy=(0.8, 0.8), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=100)
ax.add_patch(e1)
ax.add_patch(e2)

def init():
    e1.set_visible(False)
    e2.set_visible(False)
    return [e1,e2]

def animate(i):
    if i == 1:
        e1.set_visible(True)
        e2.set_visible(True)
    e1.angle = e1.angle + 0.5
    e2.angle = e2.angle + 0.5
    return [e1,e2]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
e1 = Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=60)
e2 = Ellipse(xy=(0.8, 0.8), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=100)


def init():
    return [ax]

def animate(i):
    if i==0:
        ax.add_patch(e1)
        ax.add_patch(e2)    
    e1.angle = e1.angle + 0.5
    e2.angle = e2.angle + 0.5
    return [e1,e2]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Screen-shot showing the correct behavior]

Try this other approach (not I've used only one ellipse just for testing, it also renders fine here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
e1 = Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=60)
ax.add_patch(e1)

def init():
    e1.set_visible(False)
    return e1,

def animate(i):
    if i==0:
        e1.set_visible(True)
    e1.angle = e1.angle + 0.5
    return e1,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've copy-pasted the code I posted yesterday and it works smoothly here. (Matplotlib 1.2.1)

Comment: Yes, I've copy-pasted your code, still the same as before. I'm on v1.2.1 as well.

Comment: Humm..., Well I'm using PyQt4 as back-end and I'm on Linux Min 15, maybe you have a different back-end? I'm thinking is an issue on matplotlib? I I try your code with `blit=False` it runs fine.

Comment: I've tried using a different backend (for instance `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')`), but without success. I'm on Windows 7. And yes, with `blit=False` it runs, but terribly slow

Comment: Well, maybe is a problem with W7, I've updated the answer with another idea, try it if you like.

Comment: Your last idea works! The only change I had to make was set `i == 0` to `i == 1`, otherwise nothing would show. But it works as intended now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The proposed answer seems like a hack. You're hiding the patch for one frame, then showing it the next, for no rhyme or reason. Also, I noticed the `init` function gets called whenever you resize the plot, which would then make the ellipse invisible after resizing with the proposed solution.

I think the correct way to do this is to set `animated=True` on the `Ellipse` objects. See the [matplotlib animation documentation](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Animations.html#animating-selected-plot-elements). Here's some code that works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
e1 = Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=60, animated=True)
e2 = Ellipse(xy=(0.8, 0.8), width=0.5, height=0.2, angle=100, animated=True)
ax.add_patch(e1)
ax.add_patch(e2)

def init():
    return [e1, e2]

def animate(i):
    e1.angle = e1.angle + 0.5
    e2.angle = e2.angle + 0.5
    return [e1, e2]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```