# Matplotlib animation in real time

Tags: python, performance, animation, matplotlib

In the example below I want to make an animation where a point moves around a circle in T seconds (for example T=10). However it is a lot slower and doesn't work. So, what is wrong with my code and how to fix it? As far as I understand the api (http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) setting `interval=1` should update the figure every millisecond.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

R = 3
T = 10

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(300)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-R*1.5, R*1.5))
ax.set_aspect('equal')


patch = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, fc='r')
looping = plt.Circle((0,0),R,color='b',fill=False)
ax.add_artist(looping)
time_text = ax.text(-10,R*1.2,'',fontsize=15)

def init():
    time_text.set_text('')
    patch.center = (0, 0)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,time_text,


def animate(i):
    t=i/1000.0
    time_text.set_text(t)
    x, y = patch.center
    x = R*np.sin(t/T*2*np.pi)
    y = R*np.cos(t/T*2*np.pi)
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,time_text

slow_motion_factor=1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=10000,
                               interval=1*slow_motion_factor,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I should add that the problem depends on the machine where I run the program. For example on a old Intel dualcore (P8700) (that's the box where the program should run), it is considerable slower than on a newer haswell i7 desktop cpu. But in the latter case it is also much slower as intended.

Comment: The `interval` argument specifies a *minimum* interval between frames. You can increase it in order to get a more consistent (but slower) framerate, but reducing it will not magically make your animation render faster. In practice each frame will almost certainly take longer than a millisecond to render, so what you're seeing is the difference between the maximum framerates that your two machines can manage.

Comment: If the machine cannot serve a new plot in 1ms, how can the animation be updated in 1 ms? That does not work out. Find an interval your machine is able to serve and use it. With the usual monitor rates of O(100 Hz) intervals faster than 10 ms make no real sense. I would choose something like 40 to get 25 frames per second.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your computer is not fast enough, to deliver a new image every 1 ms. Which is kind of expected.

You should go for a more realistic speed. 25 frames per second should be enough 
and also be possible to render in time.

I also made a few adjustment to you code, mostly style and more semantic variable names.
The biggest change was adapting this answer to your code to get rid of the first frame being still there after the init: 
[Matplotlib animation: first frame remains in canvas when using blit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439489/matplotlib-animation-first-frame-remains-in-canvas-when-using-blit)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

R = 3
T = 10
time = 3 * T
slow_motion_factor = 1
fps = 50
interval = 1 / fps

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect='equal')
ax.set_xlim(-1.5 * R, 1.5 * R)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5 * R, 1.5 * R)

runner = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, fc='r')
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), R, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)
time_text = ax.text(1.1 * R, 1.1 * R,'', fontsize=15)

def init():
    time_text.set_text('')
    return time_text,


def animate(i):
    if i == 0:
        ax.add_patch(runner)
    t = i * interval
    time_text.set_text('{:1.2f}'.format(t))
    x = R * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t / T)
    y = R * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t / T)
    runner.center = (x, y)
    return runner, time_text

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate,
    init_func=init,
    frames=time * fps,
    interval=1000 * interval * slow_motion_factor,
    blit=True,
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is smoother and it runs faster. But now it seems to run too fast. I do not only want a smooth animation but also a real time one. For example if I change T to 60 and use a stopwatch, it seems to take 40 real seconds to go one time around. By the way, it runs with python3 but not with python2.

Comment: `from __future__ import division` should fix it for python2. (t/T=0)