# FuncAnimation cannot blit away the first frame imshow content when blit=True?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

When using `imshow` artist in `FuncAnimation` the first frame cannot be blitted away. It will always leave the first frame untouched, but other artists behave correctly. How can we fix this?
Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation, cm
def show_imshow_blit_bug(start=0, blit=True):
    pic = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=float)
    x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
    amp = (x.max() - x.min()) / 2

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    extent = [x.min(), x.max(), -amp, amp]
    _cm = cm.jet
    picf = pic.flat
    picf[0] = 1
    picf[-1] = 0.5
    imart = ax.imshow(pic,
                      origin='lower',
                      extent=extent,
                      cmap=_cm
                      )
    # imart.set_animated(True) # set or not has no effect
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x)*amp)
    line2, = ax.plot(x[[0, -1]], np.array([-amp, amp]), 'r')
    line2.set_animated(True) # this make line2 disappear, since updater does not return this artist
    line3, = ax.plot(x[[0, -1]], np.array([amp, -amp]), 'C1')
    #line3 will be keeped since _animated = False
    ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    ax.set_ylim(-amp * 1.1, amp * 1.1)
    fig.tight_layout()

    def updater(fn):
        print(fn)
        np.random.shuffle(picf)
        imart.set_data(np.ma.masked_where(pic == 0, pic))
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + fn / 10.0)*amp)
        return (imart, line,) # Both artist will be in blit list

    nframe = range(start, 200)
    anima = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                            updater,
                            nframe,
                            interval=20,
                            blit=blit,
                            repeat=False
                            )
    plt.show()
```

I am aware there is a [hack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21441849/1492613) to set artists invisible in `init_func`. But this is a hack and I do not want to use `init_func` which is not compatible with the rest of codes.

Answer (score 0):

The [`FuncAnimation` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) states

> `init_func` : callable, optional
>
> A function used to draw a clear frame. **If not given, the results of drawing from the first item in the frames sequence will be used.** This function will be called once before the first frame.)

So using `init_func` is not a hack or undesired - it is actually the intended usage.

You would initiate an empty image

```
imart = ax.imshow([[]], ...)
```

have an init function

```
def init():
    return imart,line,
```

and an updating function

```
def updater(fn):
    np.random.shuffle(picf)
    imart.set_data(np.ma.masked_where(pic == 0, pic))
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + fn / 10.0)*amp)
    return (imart, line,)
```

and instantiate `FuncAnimation`

```
anima = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                        updater,
                        nframe,
                        init_func=init,
                        interval=20,
                        blit=blit,
                        repeat=False
                        )
```

Comment: This is a hack. Because you create an empty `imart`. If there is no `init_func`, the `_init_draw` will just call updater(0). If you look into the code, what `_init_draw` did is just register all artists returned by `init_func` with `set_animated(True)`. In theory, it should not leave any frame there. As I said this only failed with imshow. Other artists do not require an empty initial artists.

Comment: Not sure what the question is asking then. If you feel this is a bug, SO is not the right place for reporting it, go to the [matplotlib issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues). But if you consider for a moment that there might be a good reason for images not having the _animated property translated into visibility, the above is a sensible solution. Or maybe you just restate what exactly you want to ask here.